# Is this a a sign for a memory leak in Reactor?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jprofiler, project-reactor, java-memory-leaks

I have an application with a network of Fluxes processing some data. The data to be processed is received via web sockets. Except from the end of the processing pipeline where some aggregated values are stored the application should be stateless. However I see a continuous increase of the heap size. You can see this when looking at the red line which cuts the points after I triggered garbage collection:

[image]

Blue in the diagram is the *used heap* size.

If I look whats on the heap I see that classes from Reactor have the biggest impact:

[image]

However, I've never profiled a Reactor based application before and I'm not sure whether this could be a memory leak in Reactor or not. Before I made the above screenshot I triggered the garbage collection and made a heap snapshot, after initially marking the heap in JProfiler.

Does this look like a memory leak in Reactor?

Comment: Take two snapshots some time apart and only use new objects, then check if those objects really should persist on the heap

Comment: which version of Reactor-Core is that? There is indeed a retaining issue in core up to 3.1.2, fixed in 3.1.3

Comment: Thanks @IngoKegel comparing snapshots helped to view the problem more clearly.

Comment: @SimonBaslé Thanks for the hint. I've used `io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Bismuth-RELEASE` in my build.gradle what resulted in Reactor 3.1.0. Now I switched to SR5 and now have Reactor 3.1.3.